# Imprimir tabla BD oracle en PHP

Tags: php, oracle

tengo una duda es que quiero sacar una tabla en html y que me imprima todos los datos de una tabla en oracle, pero no logro hacerlo.

```
<?php

function conectar_Oracle($usuario, $pass, $cadenaconexion)
{
    // Conectar con Oracle:
    $conexion = oci_connect($usuario, $pass, $cadenaconexion) or die("Error al conectar : " . oci_error());

    return $conexion;
}

$conexion = conectar_Oracle(
    "system",
    "password",
    "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=puvidb)))"
);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM GENERAL.PERSONAGENERAL ORDER BY 'PAGE_ID'";
$filas = 0;

$stmt = oci_parse($conexion, $sql);
$ok   = oci_execute($stmt);
$obj = oci_fetch_object($stmt);
echo $obj->PEGE_ID . " - " . $obj->PEGE_DOCUMENTOIDENTIDAD . " - " . $obj->PEGE_MAIL . "<br />";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <table border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Codigo</th>
                <th>Producto</th>
                <th>Stock</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php
            $i = 1;
            foreach ($obj as $dato) {
            ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $i++; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $obj->PEGE_ID; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $obj->PEGE_DOCUMENTOIDENTIDAD; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $obj->PEGE_MAIL; ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
        </tbody>
        </div>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Pues logro que me traiga datos cuando lo especifico, pero no me trae toda la table, quiere decir que la conexion aprece estar todo correcto, estoy muy acostumbrado es a las conectarme con MySQL pero oracle he tenido muchos problemas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui hay esta el resultado, si se dan cuenta me repite los datos y no me trae los datos demas, tengo que decir que esta BD tiene cerca de 2500 registros

Comment: Saludos. Tiempo que no uso **PHP** y el `foreach` no lo use (https://www.php.net/manual/es/control-structures.foreach.php) pero creo que en vez de (por ejemplo) `<td><?php echo $obj->PEGE_ID; ?></td>` debe ser `<td><?php echo $dato->PEGE_ID; ?></td>` y así para los demás.

Comment: Notice: Trying to get property 'PEGE_ID' of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\Pasarela\conexion.php on line 51 Me sale este error, }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La falla es que el foreach esta mal hecho y ya que las variables que estab definidas ahi no funcionan. el codigo quedaria así.

```
<?php

$conn = oci_connect(
    "system",
    "password",
    "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=puvidb)))"
);
if (!$conn) {
    $e = oci_error();
    trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
}
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM GENERAL.PERSONAGENERAL WHERE PEGE_ID > 12000 AND PEGE_ID < 12100';
$stid = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
oci_execute($stid);

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM ACADEMICO.ESTUDIANTEPENSUM WHERE ';





?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <table border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Codigo</th>
                <th>Producto</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php
            $i = 1;
            while (oci_fetch($stid)) {

            ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $i++; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo oci_result($stid, 'PEGE_ID'); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo oci_result($stid, 'PEGE_DOCUMENTOIDENTIDAD'); ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php
            }
            oci_free_statement($stid);
            oci_close($conn);

            ?>
        </tbody>
        </div>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```